# pex built by pex doesn't run outside its virtualenv

Tags: python, twitter, pex

*TL;DR*

I built `pex` according to the guide https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.145/buildingpex.html and was expecting it to run fine outside of the virtualenv I used to build it, but alas:

```
$ ~/bin/pex
env: python3.9: No such file or directory
```

*What I tried*

I am reading pex's guide https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.145/buildingpex.html and following their first "recipe" to build `pex` itself

> You can build .pex files using the pex utility, which is made available when you pip install pex.
> Do this within a virtualenv, then you can use pex to bootstrap itself:

- In an empty directory, I created a fresh `venv`

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
```

- Activate the `venv`

```
$ . venv/bin/activate
```

- Insatll `pex`

```
(venv) tmp $ pip install pex
Collecting pex
  Downloading pex-2.1.145-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.9 MB 4.1 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pex
Successfully installed pex-2.1.145
```

- Build `pex`

```
$ pex pex requests -c pex -o ~/bin/pex
```

- Try `pex` interactively

```
$ pex
Python 3.9.6 (default, May  7 2023, 23:32:44)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> ^D
now exiting InteractiveConsole...
```

- The documentation says:

> you can use pex in or outside of any virtualenv.

- Therefore, I deactivate the `venv` and then try to run `pex` again:

```
$ deactivate
$ ~/bin/pex
env: python3.9: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

*Additional information*

Platform: MacOS Ventura 13.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65674539/pyyaml-dependency-error-while-executing-with-python-script-in-pex) I learned about the `--python-shebang` option.

In my case, I first searched the path of the Python 3 interpreter on the system:

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

then re-built `pex` instide the VirtualEnv but specifying the shebang line with the Python 3 path on my system:

```
$ pex pex requests -c pex -o ~/bin/pex --python-shebang '#!/usr/bin/env python3'
```

Now I can exit the VirtualEnv and `pex` still works:

```
$ deactivate
$ ~/bin/pex
Python 3.9.6 (default, May  7 2023, 23:32:44)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> ^D
now exiting InteractiveConsole...
```